# How to read from text file different lines and what and how many vowels are in the text presented

Tags: c#

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string start = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\file.txt";

            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(start))
            {
                string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(start);

                int len = lines.Length;

                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                {

                    if (ReadText[i] == 'a' || ReadText[i] == 'e' || ReadText[i] == 'i' || ReadText[i] == 'o' || ReadText[i] == 'u' || ReadText[i] == 'A' || ReadText[i] == 'E' || ReadText[i] == 'I' || ReadText[i] == 'O' || ReadText[i] == 'U')
                    {
                        vowel++;
                    }
                }
                richTextBox3.AppendText(Convert.ToString(vowel) + " ");
            }
        }
```

How to read from text file different lines and what and how many vowels are in the text presented. Firstly, I'm trying to get access to 5-6-7 lines from this text file: https://gyazo.com/7618175d9c948eb73d0eae5ad322e9c8
And then i want to scan 5-6-7 lines and see what and hwo many vowels in it. 
And I want to print it in TextBox like this: 
just for example: 
a is: 5 \n
e is: 7 \n
....

Comment: File.ReadAllLines... this method will give you seperate lines instead of one big blob

Comment: Not sure how you edited your post, ReadText is no longer a variable :)

Comment: `var regx = new Regex("a|e|i|o|u", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); var matches = regx.Matches("Some text"); string result = string.Join(" ", matches.OfType<Match>().SelectMany(m => m.Value));`

Comment: What does `a is: 5` represent? Does it mean there is one `a` on line 5? Or does it mean there are 5 `a`s on all the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```cs
var filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\file.txt";
var count = 0;
var vowels = new[] { 'a', 'e', 'i',  'o', 'u' };

foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(4).Take(3))
    count += line.Count(c => vowels.Contains(char.ToLowerInvariant(c)));

Console.WriteLine(count);
```

This will get the required lines only from the text file (5, 6, and 7) and get the total count of the vowels from them.

If you want to get the count of each vowel, then you could do instead:

```cs
var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>
{
    { 'a', 0 },
    { 'e', 0 },
    { 'i', 0 },
    { 'o', 0 },
    { 'u', 0 },
};

foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath).Skip(4).Take(3))
    foreach(var kvp in dict.ToList())
        dict[kvp.Key] += line.Count(c => kvp.Key.Equals(char.ToLowerInvariant(c)));

foreach (var kvp in dict)
    Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key} : {kvp.Value}");
```

Comment: When using `Skip`/`Take` with files, you should use `ReadLines` and not `ReadAllLines`, which reads the entire file into memory only to throw most of it away. Also, instead of `dict.ToList()` use `var vowelchar in dict.Keys` and you don't need the repeated `.Key` and wasting time on the unused `.Value`.

Comment: @NetMage Absolutely right, just noticed that. I'll keep it as is to tell - along with your valuable comment - the right and the wrong ways. Also, thank you for your beautiful post.

Comment: No problem. I also notice this is a good use case for my `AutoDictionary` that implements auto-vivification ala Perl, which was designed for this case (doesn't require dictionary initialization).

Answer (score 1):

First, create a data structure to test for vowels:

```
var vowels = "aeiou".ToHashSet();
```

Then a data structure to remember which lines are of interest:

```
var interestingLineNumbers = new[] { 5, 6, 7 }.ToHashSet();
var maxInterestingLineNumber = interestingLineNumbers.Max();
```

Now you can pull the interesting lines from the file by reading up to the last interesting line, and keeping the lines of interest:

```
var linesOfInterest = File.ReadLines(filename).Take(maxInterestingLineNumber).Where((l,i) => interestingLineNumbers.Contains(i+1));
```

Now for each line of interest, pull out the vowels and then count the total vowels:

```
var vowelCounts = linesOfInterest.SelectMany(l => l.ToLower().Where(ch => vowels.Contains(ch)))
                                 .GroupBy(vch => vch)
                                 .OrderBy(vg => vg.Key) // optional ordering
                                 .Select(vg => $"{vg.Key} is: {vg.Count()}");
```

Combine the vowel lines to create the `TextBox` text value:

```
var text = String.Join('\n', vowelCounts);
```

If it isn't important, you could leave out the ordering by removing the `OrderBy` line.
If you need to remember whether the vowel was upper or lowercase, you could extend `vowels` to include the uppercase vowels and remove the `ToLower`. Unicode vowel identification is problematic, so I just went with listing the ones you care about.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines and then pick line 5, 6 and 7. Then check vowels in all.

```
string[] ReadLines = File.ReadAllLines(start);
string line = string.Empty;

if (ReadLines.Count() > 7)
{
    line = $"{ReadLines[4]}{ReadLines[5]}{ReadLines[6]}".ToLower();
}
else
{
    line = string.Join("", ReadLines);
}

int len = line.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    if (line[i] == 'a' || line[i] == 'e' || line[i] == 'i' || line[i] == 'o' || line[i] == 'u')
    {
        vowel++;
    }
}

richTextBox3.AppendText(vowel.ToString() + " ");
```

Comment: make sure to mark the post as answer if this resolves your issues